# jQuery hover with background image transition/ease effect

Tags: jquery, hover

I'm wondering and have searched all around and can't find the answer. Right now I'm changing a background image using jQuery, on hover. Is it possible to add a transition time in it? Like a fade? ie8 compatible?

Here's the code:

```
$('.logo').hover(function() {
    $(this).css("background","url('url') no-repeat"); 
},function() {
    $(this).css("background","url('url_hover') no-repeat"); 
});
```

Comment: Have you tried using the [CSS transition property](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp)? This seems like something that could be done in pure CSS

Comment: That doesn't work when using background images, only if using the <img> tag. Either way I've seen some solutions to go over it though I want it to work on IE8 aswell so CSS3 is irrelevant.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/animate/ ENJOY!

Comment: @SpYk3HH animate doesn't support images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the background image source isn't a property of gradation, maybe make two mock backgrounds positioned behind all elements and fade one out on hover to reveal the one behind it.

You could do something like this - [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BrianDillingham/own63jvh/)

HTML

```
<div class="bgFadeToggle">
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    <div class="bg"><img src="image-1.jpg" /></div>
    <div class="bg"><img src="image-2.jpg" /></div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('.bgFadeToggle').hover(function(){
    $(this).find('.bg:first').stop(true).fadeToggle();
});
```

CSS

```
.bgFadeToggle {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9999;
}

.bgFadeToggle .bg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.bgFadeToggle .bg  {
    z-index: -9998;
}

.bgFadeToggle .bg + .bg {
    z-index: -9999;
}
```

Comment: Was thinking of editing to only have one mock `.bg` and use the bg of `#element` as the default. Thoughts?

Comment: Give it a try, I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: Also, do you think it's possible to create a unique js to make it work for all images that I want to enable this fade transition? Something that I just had to add some class to the image or the parent and it'll enable a smooth transition.

Comment: Updated, I think its work another upvote personally :)

Comment: That's impressive! Though I can only work with background-image :(

Comment: If you have to use a background image vs an image acting as a background within the markup, you're going to have to declare the css for each instance and a dynamic solution would only be possible with a strict naming convention

Comment: Well yes, I'd have to have CSS though about the javascript is it possible to have the same for several?

Comment: You can apply the code Ive provided in many ways, yes its possible :) happy coding